# Hide OPTIONS endpoint from Swagger UI using serverless

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger-ui, serverless

I have set cors: true for each endpoint in the serverless YAML file. However, I do not want to show "OPTIONS" endpoint in the swagger UI for the same. I am using the serverless framework and below is the code for sample endpoint:

```
sample name:
    handler: path/to/the/handler/
    events:
      - http:
          path: v1/sample
          method: get
          cors: true
          private: true
          documentation:
            summary: "summary of the endpoint"
            methodResponses:
              - statusCode: "200"
                responseBody:
                  description: "response body"
                responseModels:
                  "application/json": "response model"
```

I am expecting that OPTIONS should NOT be visible on Swagger UI despite the CORS is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the `OPTIONS` method endpoint is necessary for CORS to function correctly as it's the method used in the [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) that checks CORS viability.

AWS Swagger exports do include the `OPTIONS` endpoint in quite an intrusive way. If you don't want it in your Swagger UI I suggest you programmatically filter the `OPTIONS` endpoints out of the Swagger file after exporting it from API Gateway, before using it for Swagger UI (depending on how you construct your Swagger UI).